# Editing volume of a wav file on a Zoom H4n

Tags: editing

is there a way to edit the volume of a wav. file after it has been recorded on a Zoom H4n?

Comment: Welcome to sound.SE. We are a QA site, not an online answering machine. While your question is pretty clear, it also doesn't show much effort. What problem exactly do you whish to solve? Why do you need to change the level right in the H4n? (If not, then the answer is obviously: yes, you can change the volume of a `.wav` file!)

Comment: this question is so basic that you will likely get many answers... the question is better suited for this site if you ask how it can be edited and when you explain why you want to do it (like @leftaroundabout already stated).

Answer (score 1):

On the device itself, I don't know the answer..you certainly have many more options related to volume processing once you move the audio file onto your computer, which you will end up having to do to make any use of it.

For info on connecting the Zoom to the computer, see the manual.

For free audio editing/processing software see "Audacity"

For more complicated audio problems than changing the volume up or down (for example, distortion, noise, clipping, or reverberations), there are other tools you can use which are often plugins marketed for "audio repair" or "restoration."  They take training and practice to use!